# How to use TIdHTTPSession in TIdHTTPServer?

Tags: delphi

I don't understand the idea of TIdHTTPSession in TIdHTTPServer. What is it for? Is it a kind of container for request, or what is it? How do I use it properly after I have enabled `AutoSessionStart`? And what will happen if I do not enable `AutoSessions`?

For example, say we have some shared resourse `FMyMessages: TStringList;` Then how should I request this shared resource with/without sessions?

`TIdHTTPSession` has an `FLock: TIdCriticalSection;` member - so maybe I should use it to lock my shared resource `FMyMessages` from other threads if I have `AutoSessions`, otherwise I should use my own critical section?

Also, how can I count Sessions in the moment? I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
Server.Contexts.Count.ToString;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand the idea of TIdHTTPSession in TIdHTTPServer ? What is it for? Is it a kind of container for request, or what is it? How do I use it properly after I have enabled `AutoSessionStart`?

HTTP is a stateless protocol. It does not remember information from one request to the next. And it does not even guarantee or require that the TCP connection itself remain open between requests.

That is where sessions come into play. The server can create a session object to store information, such as during a client login, and that session's unique ID is sent to the client via an HTTP cookie, which the client can send back to the server on subsequent requests to reuse the same session object. Eventually, the session will timeout and be destroyed, if you do not end the session explicitly, such as during client logout.

> And what will happen if I do not enable `AutoSessions`?

The server will simply not *automatically* create a new session object if one does not exist yet for each request. You would have to create a new session manually on an as-needed basis instead.

> For example, say we have some shared resourse `FMyMessages: TStringList;` Then how should I request this shared resource with/without sessions?

Sessions have nothing to do with accessing shared resources, and everything to do with persisting per-client state data. Such as user logins, database connections, etc.

> `TIdHTTPSession` has an `FLock: TIdCriticalSection;` member - so maybe I should use it to lock my shared resource `FMyMessages` from other threads if I have `AutoSessions`, otherwise I should use my own critical section?

No. You can use Indy's `TIdThreadSafeStringList` instead.

> Also, how can I count Sessions in the moment? I tried like this but it doesn't work:
>
> ```
> Server.Contexts.Count.ToString;
> ```

The `Contexts` property stores the active client TCP connections. That has nothing to do with HTTP sessions. Those are stored in the server's `SessionList` property instead.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me in understanding of idHTTPSession.